# How to setup Atom's 'styles.less' file to highlight function and method call in Python?

Tags: python, css, atom-editor

I would like to have it highlighted like here in Sublime Text:

[image]

I tried like suggested [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-change-the-color-of-python-function-calls/22660/3):

```css
atom-text-editor, atom-text-editor::shadow {
  .meta.function-call.python {
    color: '#abcde';
  }
}
```

However, Atom's deprecation says:

> Starting from Atom v1.13.0, the contents of `atom-text-editor` elements
>   are no longer encapsulated within a shadow DOM boundary. This means
>   you should stop using `:host` and `::shadow` pseudo-selectors, and prepend
>   all your syntax selectors with `syntax--`. To prevent breakage with
>   existing style sheets, Atom will automatically upgrade the following
>   selectors:
>
> - `atom-text-editor .meta.function-call.generic.python`,
> - `atom-text-editor::shadow .meta.function-call.generic.python` =>
>     `atom-text-editor .meta.function-call.generic.python`,
> - `atom-text-editor.editor
>     .syntax--meta.syntax--function-call.syntax--generic.syntax--python`
>
> Automatic translation of selectors will be removed in a few release
>   cycles to minimize startup time. Please, make sure to upgrade the
>   above selectors as soon as possible.

Should it be like this? (I tried but it doesn't work)

```css
atom-text-editor {
  .meta.function-call.python {
    color: '#66D9EF';
  }
}

atom-text-editor.editor {
  .syntax--meta.syntax--function-call.syntax--python {
    color: '#66D9EF';
  }
}
```

Could someone help me to highlight function and method calls in Atom's Monokai syntax color theme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the `''` from the color rule. Those don't go there. I tested and this works:

```css
atom-text-editor.editor {
  .syntax--meta.syntax--function-call.syntax--python {
    color: #66D9EF;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this highlights all the code: instance name, method, parentheses and parameters. I guess, I should use this: `.meta.function-call.generic.python` but don't know how?

Comment: The same way the rest of it is done. The selector would simply read `.syntax--meta.syntax--function-call.syntax--generic.syntax--python`.

Comment: I don't know what am I doing wrong. Maybe Monokao theme doesn't support this scope http://imgur.com/a/6Qrt7

Comment: The theme only provides style rules. It's the language package that determines which classes are applied. It seems like the base `language-python` package doesn't support it. However, [`magicpython`](https://atom.io/packages/MagicPython) does.

Comment: Thanks! Material theme and magicpython seems to work. http://imgur.com/a/9QJWU How can I find a scope and edit Monokai theme? It seems colors are the same in it.

Comment: Atom has the Chrome dev tools that you can use to dig into how everything is displayed. Your theme *should* have no impact on rules defined in `styles.less`, unless the theme includes a selector with so many entities that its priority is through the roof.

Answer (score 0):

This solution highlighted all function calls for me:

```
atom-text-editor.editor {
  .syntax--source.syntax--python {
    .syntax--function-call.syntax--generic.syntax--python  {
      color: #ffc1c1;
    }
  }
}
```