# Atom editor's style.less customization for languages

Tags: css, less, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

Reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721230/), I figured out how to change Atom's syntax highlighting for MATLAB by editing the `styles.less` file. Here is [the full description](http://qiita.com/kouichi-c-nakamura/items/937a729a0d505fcb823d)

```
atom-text-editor.editor {
  .syntax--source.syntax--matlab {
    .syntax--meta.syntax--variable.syntax--other.syntax--valid.syntax--matlab {
      color: #000000; //black
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I trid to use the same principle for changing font setting for markdown (scope is `text.md`), it didn't work.

```
atom-text-editor.editor {
  .sytax--text.syntax--md {
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
  }
}
```

However, this works fine.

```
atom-text-editor[data-grammar="text md"],
atom-text-editor[data-grammar="text md"].editor {
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
```

Can anybody suggest what's the logic behind this behavior? Why doesn't the same method for MATLAB take an effect on markdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anybody suggest what's the logic behind this behavior?

You misspelled the `syntax` in `syntax--text`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your eagle eyes. It's a bit embarrassing, but I'm glad you found it.